# Travis (Windows): Undefined method 'try'

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I have absolutely no clue about Ruby, I am only trying to use it to encrypt parameters for my .travis.yml. Whenever I run `travis pubkey -r user/project` I get the error

```
undefined method `try' for #<Faraday::Env:0x289a748>
for a full error report, run travis report
```

The full report is (I changed some private data):

```
C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Dev\WorkspacePhpStorm\xyz>travis report
System
Ruby:                     Ruby 2.1.3-p242
Operating System:         Windows
RubyGems:                 RubyGems 2.2.2

CLI
Version:                  1.7.5
Plugins:                  none
Auto-Completion:          yes
Last Version Check:       2015-01-22 10:16:22 +0100

Session
API Endpoint:             https://api.travis-ci.org/
Logged In:                no
Verify SSL:               yes
Enterprise:               no

Endpoints
org:                      https://api.travis-ci.org/ (current)

Last Exception
An error occurred running `travis pubkey`:
NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for #<Faraday::Env:0x289a748>
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/remote.rb:71:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/normalizer.rb:8:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/parallel.rb:27:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/wrapper.rb:87:in `generate_response'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/remote.rb:88:in `request'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gh-0.13.3/lib/gh/remote.rb:106:in `head'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.7.5/lib/travis/cli/repo_command.rb:111:in `detect_api_endpoint'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.7.5/lib/travis/cli/repo_command.rb:23:in `setup'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.7.5/lib/travis/cli/command.rb:197:in `execute'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.7.5/lib/travis/cli.rb:64:in `run'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.7.5/bin/travis:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/bin/travis:23:in `load'
    from C:/Users/xyz/Documents/Dev/Tools/Ruby21/bin/travis:23:in `<main>'

For issues with the command line tool, please visit https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues.
For Travis CI in general, go to https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues or email support@travis-ci.com.
```

Is anyone able to tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Most probably gem [faraday](https://rubygems.org/gems/faraday) is missing. Try installing it by adding following to your gemfile:

```
gem 'faraday'
```

Followed by

```
bundle install
```

**Alternatively**:

```
gem install faraday
```

Comment: I did a `gem install faraday` and the command now runs without the error from above. Thank you so much. I am only wondering why `gem install travis` does not install all the dependencies. Is that an error which needs to be reported to travis-cli?

Comment: Sorry, I have to reject my answer. It does not help. I discovered that there is a `travis login` and tried it but got a "Validation Failed" error (my credentials were correct). I then tried `travis pubkey -r ....` again without the try error. It said `incorrect data check`. If I now run it again I get the 'try' error from above again :-(

Comment: try `gem install faraday -v 0.9.0`. Latest faraday version i.e. 0.9.1 may have incompatibility issues with your `travis-1.7.5`. PS: its a guess

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue on the github which explains what is going on: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues/265

TL;DR: Downgrade gh:

```
gem uninstall gh
gem install gh -v 0.13.2
```